# Replicate sublist in new list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list of lists $a$ and a list of occurrences of each sublist $n$

```
a={ {1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3} }
n={1,3,2}
```

what is the most efficient way to get the following list?

```
l={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}}
```

My current implementation is

```
l=Flatten[Table[Table[a[[i]],{x,n[[i]]}],{i,Range[Length[n]]}],1]
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for the answers!

For the problem as posted, the fastest solution is `Catenate[...]` from `march` (inspired by `J.M.`) at 1.7 10^-5 seconds (AbsoluteTiming), with all other solutions being above 2 10^-5.

If I drastically increase the number of samples I want (for example multiplying n*100), then `Catenate[MapThread[Table, {a, List /@ n}]];` takes 1.5 10^-3 seconds and the fastest solution by far is `a[[Join @@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1] &, n]]];` from `ubpdqn`, at 7.7 10^-5.

In both cases, solutions from `garej` had intermediate timings.

So I guess the ideal solution depends on the exact problem (size of the array, number of samples, ...) and may or may not have a great impact on the overall performance.

Comment: `Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray, {a, n}], 1]`?

Comment: @Delphine If you're using Mma 10, I think `Catenate` will be about 20% faster than `Flatten[..., 1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a[[Join @@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1] &, n]]]
```

Comment: Your solution is actually the fastest. Can you explain a bit what it does?

Comment: @Delphine `MapIndexed` uses the index as position in list.`ConstantArray` just produces the desired number of the position. `Join` just makes a flat list and then you just use `Part` (`[[...]]`) to select the desired outcome. @MartinButtner notes `Catenate` is faster. This could also be used.

Comment: @ubpdqn, If possible please tell why did not you use of `Flatten` instead of `Join`? is there any special reason?

Comment: @Irreversible   No special reason. Could use Join.

Answer (score 5):

```
Table @@@ Transpose[{a, n}] // Catenate
```

> `{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}}`

**Edit** Also

```
Join @@ Table @@@ Thread[{a, n}]
```

Comment: These are good solutions too, very elegant, but not the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

From a comment by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), what I consider to be the most natural solution:

```
Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray, {a, n}], 1];
```

Via [Martin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-b%c3%bcttner), alternatively do

```
MapThread[ConstantArray, {a, n}] // Catenate;
```

You can also do something similar using pure functions and `Apply`:

```
ConstantArray[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread[{a, n}] // Catenate;
```

This is just about as fast as the previous version. You can also get around having to `Catenate` at the end by using `Sequence` all along the way, i.e.

```
Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread[{a, n}];
```

but it turns out that this is a little slower (maybe 25% slower).

I tried to come up with a `ReplaceAll` version, but they were all ten times slower.

The fastest so far seems to be again by J.M. Pre 10.2 version is

```
Catenate[MapThread[Table, {a, List /@ n}]];
```

and 10.2 and later is

```
Catenate[MapThread[Table, {a, n}]];
```

Comment: Apparently `Table[]` also works: `Catenate[MapThread[Table, {a, n}]]`

Comment: @J.M. Perhaps in version newer than V10.0. I had to do `Catenate[MapThread[Table, {a, List /@ n}]]` to make that work, but it turned out to be 4 times faster than the others!

Comment: yes, that's the classical syntax for `Table[]`: `Table[1, {5}]`. Thus my surprise when I forgot to put in the list for the iterator and it worked anyway.

Comment: I varied the size of the array a and the number of replicates n. It appears this last solution is the fastest, but only if the arrays or the number of replicates are small.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};
n = {1, 3, 2};
```

Using `Splice` (new in 12.1) and `ReplicateLayer` (new in 11.1)

```
Round @ MapThread[Splice @* ReplicateLayer[#2] @ #1 &, {list, n}]
```

{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}}

Since `ReplicateLayer` returns a packed array of reals we use `Round`